# Error in :: NA/NaN argument

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I am creating a shiny app, but the table5 does not work and R says **`Error in :: NA/NaN argument`**.  Anyone has any idea about what's happening now? For tabale 5, I am using the data in table 1 and table 2...

Another question is inside the shiny app, there are a lot data clean, should I put the data clean outside the shiny app? or should I just leave the data clean inside the app? Which one is more efficient?

Thanks so much!

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)
library(tidyr)


Index_2 <- read_xlsx('Index 2.xlsx')
Index_11 <- read_xlsx('Index 11.xlsx')
whole_country_list <- read_xlsx('whole country list.xlsx')
country_list <- sort(unique(whole_country_list$`Country Name`)) 

Index_2 <- filter(Index_2, Country  %in% whole_country_list$`whole list`) %>%
  left_join(whole_country_list, by = c("Country" = "whole list" )) %>%
  select(- Country) %>%
  select(`Country Name`, everything())

Index_11 <- filter(Index_11, Country  %in% whole_country_list$`whole list`) %>%
  left_join(whole_country_list, by = c("Country" = "whole list" )) %>%
  select(- Country) %>%
  select(`Country Name`, everything())


ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(     

  titlePanel("Input panel"),

  sidebarLayout( 
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("country_in",
                  "Choose one country:",
                  choices = country_list,
                  selected = 'Benin')
    ),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(  
        tabPanel("VAR 2:Meta data on school system, computed from INDEX 2", dataTableOutput("table1")),
        tabPanel("VAR 3: Population data, computed from INDEX 11", dataTableOutput("table2")),
        tabPanel("VAR 4: School-age population data, computed from VAR 2 AND 3", dataTableOutput("table5"))
      )
    )
  )
) 
) 




server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

  dataInput1 <- reactive({
    out <- dplyr::filter(Index_2, `Country Name`  == input$country_in)
    out})

  dataInput2 <- reactive({
    out <- filter(Index_11, `Country Name`  == input$country_in & `INDEX 11: Popuiation indicators` %in%
                    c("Age population, age 03, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 03, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 04, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 04, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 05, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 05, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 06, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 06, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 07, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 07, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 08, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 08, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 09, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 09, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 10, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 10, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 11, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 11, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 12, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 12, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 13, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 13, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 14, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 14, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 15, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 15, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 16, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 16, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 17, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 17, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 18, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 18, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 19, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 19, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 20, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 20, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 21, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 21, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 22, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 22, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 23, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 23, male, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 24, female, interpolated",
                      "Age population, age 24, male, interpolated"
                    )) %>%
      separate(col = `INDEX 11: Popuiation indicators`, into = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "Age", "Sex", "X6", "X7"),  sep = ' ')%>%
      mutate( 
        Age = as.numeric(gsub(",","", Age)), 
        Sex = gsub(",","", Sex)) %>%   
      select(`Country Name`, Sex, Age, `2008`:`2050`) %>% 
      arrange(desc(Sex), Age) 
    out}) 


  dataInput5 <- reactive({
    out <-  as.data.frame(mapply(function(x,y) {
      c(y[x[1]-2],                    # first acceptable age
        sum(y[(x[1]-2):(x[1]-2+x[2])]),  # sum within range
        y[x[1]-2+x[2]])                  # last acceptable age
    },
    dataInput1()[-c(1:2)],dataInput2()[-c(1:3)])
    ) 
    out})

  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({
    dataInput1()
  })

  output$table2 <- renderDataTable({
    dataInput2()
  })

  output$table5 <- renderDataTable({
    dataInput5()
  })
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In general we ask for *reproducible* examples, but much more so for one like this where it sounds data related. Could you please try it using a built-in data set instead of XLSX? If it works you have a data problem only an owner of your data can solve. If it fails you have a reproducible example fit for StackOverflow!

Comment: Thank you hack, but the thing is if I use a built-in data, the error will disappear. Maybe I need to check the raw data,

Comment: O M G I KNOW WHERE I AM WRONG NOW. THE CODE IS FINE BUT THERE ARE EMPTY CELLS IN THE RAW DATA. Thank you so much.

Comment: Happy to help, good luck